# Access REST API in SwiftUI preview

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple view with list of data:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = AdListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List(model.adList, id: \._id) { ad in
            Text(String(describing: ad._id ?? -1))
        }
    }
}
```

where model fetches data from REST API:

```
final class AdListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var adList = [Ad]()
    init() {
        DataAccessAPI.getAllAd(page: 1) { ads, error in
            if (error == nil) {
                if let newAds = ads {
                    self.adList.append(contentsOf: newAds)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to fetch data in preview mode?

Comment: Why, it's not the purpose of the preview? It might be possible but I am convinced you risk making the preview functionality very slow.

Comment: Previews are for quick UI iteration, not testing your integration dependencies. Better to take a snapshot of this data that you can load from disk quickly each time or create some dummy data objects to use.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, in Live/Debug Preview.

Comment: @Asperi thank you, I missed this feature. It's really what I want.